# Live stream playing

Tags: php, stream, ffmpeg, live

well, I can capture the incoming stream. Its produced by FFMpeg. The php code Im doing it with:

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 1234;
$outfile = "output.flv";

$ofp = fopen($outfile, 'w');

 if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) { echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) { echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) { echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) { echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); break; }
 do {
    $a = '';
    socket_recv ($msgsock, $a, 65536, MSG_WAITALL);
    fwrite ($ofp, $a);
    echo strlen($a);
 } while (true);
```

so it produces good file, if I replay this it looks good. But I want to stream it on a site, if I just put a link to the .flv, it would play it from the beginning. How to make it real live? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can just add the flow player/JW player. This player helps you to display the video files in the server, once they are captured. You can customize and embed the video streams into web pages. This tool would bring you the [live streaming](http://hioxindia.com/live-stream-hosting.php).

Comment: can you give me an example for using this player?